# SOLR stress test using only curl calls

Tags: curl, solr, client

I would like to stress test a SOLR environment that consists of 5 agents behind a load-balancer. Each agent has 10 cores. I am new to SOLR and curl so appreciate any input.

The solution I have in mind is to create a number of clients each of which runs a python script that makes simple curl calls. The curl calls are created by iterating over queries captured in one or more text files (perhaps one file per core). One curl call per query.

probably initially I would just be interested in capturing pass or fail for each call/query and perhaps time.

Is there a downside to this approach?

What options I have for the input (files/format) for the stress test as well as for the output to avoid massive amount of query result data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are far better tools available for HTTP load testing than curl. Some of the most popular include [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), [httpref](http://sourceforge.net/projects/httperf/) and [siege](http://www.joedog.org/siege-manual/). Even [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) (Apache HTTPD Benchmarking Tool) is far more useful than curl.

When doing performance tests, be sure what you want to actually test. Outliers, 95 percentile performance, load handling under different stress situations, etc.

Most of the more serious tools also support log replay to recreate actual production load.

Comment: Thanks, how does jmeter fair against solrj. Does jmeter allow capturing solr query results (for later parsing)?

Comment: JMeter can replay log files from a variety of web servers, so it's independent from SolrJ or any Solr client. Depending on your setup you  can either use the native log format of your webserver or set it up to log in a format that JMeter can replay.